# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, coffeescript

I'm trying to make use of Typescript typings for you Youtube Data API here: https://github.com/Bolisov/typings-gapi/tree/master/gapi.client.youtube-v3

I am using Ionic framework and I receive the error below after I do Ionic Serve with the following line in code:

```
  gapi.client.load("client", "v3");

Module parse failed: /Users/yoko/Desktop/myApp/node_modules/gapi/lib/gapi.coffee Unexpected token (1:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| config = require './config'
| 
| module.exports =
```

This is how the api.coffee looks like

```
config = require './config'

module.exports =
  server:
    setApiKey: (apiKey) ->
      config.api.key = apiKey
    load: (apiName, apiVersion, callback) ->
      @[apiName] = require "./#{apiName}/#{apiVersion}"
      callback()
```

What does that mean?

Comment: Means you need to setup cofeescript transpilation.

Comment: How do I setup this in an angular project?

Comment: Need to use the loader, SystemJS, or Webpack or you can run a watch task that compiles the files to JS and include those

Comment: Can you give me an example or put on the direction how? I see a gapi.coffee file and in my angular/ionic project how do I sue the loader or webpack?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Gulp, install CoffeeScript via npm, then add it to your `package.json` via:

```
npm install gulp-coffee --save-dev #devDependencies
```

or

```
npm install gulp-coffee --save #dependencies
```

Then add the following to your Gulpfile.js:

```
var coffee = require('gulp-coffee');
var paths =  { coffee: ['/Users/yoko/Desktop/myApp/node_modules/gapi/lib/*.coffee'] };

function coffeePipe(done) 
  {
  gulp.src(paths.coffee)
    .pipe(coffee({bare: true})
    .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Coffee Error')))
    .pipe(concat('application.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/js'))
    .on('end', done)
  }

gulp.task('coffee', coffeePipe);
```

**References**

- [CoffeeScript-Ionic-Starter/gulpfile.js at master · StephenGrider/CoffeeScript-Ionic-Starter](https://github.com/StephenGrider/CoffeeScript-Ionic-Starter/blob/master/gulpfile.js)
- [Introduction to Gulp.js with practical examples | Julien Renaux Blog](https://julienrenaux.fr/2014/05/25/introduction-to-gulp-js-with-practical-examples/)
- [gulp-coffee](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-coffee)
- [05 - Using a `package.json` | npm Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json#specifying-packages)
- [Quick tip: using gulp to customize the 'serve', 'run' and 'build' process for your Ionic framework apps by leob on CodePen](https://codepen.io/leob6/post/quick-tip-using-gulp-to-customize-the-serve-run-and-build-process-for-your-ionic-framework-apps)
- [Alter The Ionic 2 Gulp Script To Include Browser JavaScript Files](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/06/alter-ionic-2-gulp-script-include-browser-javascript-files/)
- [10 Minutes with Ionic 2: Hello World | The Official Ionic Blog](http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-hello-world/)
- [Why You Should Not Use Ionic Serve For Hybrid Apps](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/02/why-you-should-not-use-ionic-serve-for-hybrid-apps/)